# .NET | SELENIUM | Get the IWebElement clicked by left mouse. Capture all clicked elements

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Good evening together,

I am struggling with this problem the last couple hours. I want to be able to get all elements (IWebElement) that are being clicked by a user (with mouse). I am looking for a way to use such as a eventhandler.

I came up with the EventFiringWebDriver Method - Does not work because it only fires when an element is clicked programmatically ( .Click() - function).
Then I tried to do it with injecting Javascript. That works so far but it stores the last Element in a var and I have to retrieve it manually after each click....

Is there a way how I can handle it propperly?

The scenario I want to use this event handler is for a Automation Framework where all clicks and the underlying element is recorded.

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very neat solution. There is a library/extension to the EventFiringWebDriver Method that does exactly what I want it to do.

https://github.com/AbrahamSanders/Selenium.WebDriver.EventCapture

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer since the reputation is not allowing to comment.

If you could manage to store the last element in a `var`, you can probably update the same script to save all such elements to a JS array during each click. After completing the test execution, you can query that variable just once to retrieve the array. You can even consider using HTML5 Web Storage or something similar to store the array.

Comment: That would be a possible way to go. But see me answer, that's the best way to achieve it.